# How to fix 'Table' object has no attribute' in Python - SQL

Tags: python, sql

This is summary of my code:

```
Players = Table('Players',meta,Column('name',String),
            Column('number',Integer),
            Column('Speed(km/h)',Float))
s = select([text(Players.name,Players.number)]).where(text('Players.number<10'))
 conn = engine.connect()
```

It has an error:

> ----> 9 s = select([text(Players.name,Players.number)]).where(text('Players.number<10'))
>   AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'number'

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and tell us what framework you are using.

Comment: Please, what framework? Are you talking about python-sql https://pypi.org/project/python-sql  ?

Comment: I am using Python Framework and i import sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.sql. I am so sory if my question is not clear.

Comment: I have cut the above, sory guys: from sqlalchemy import Table,Column,MetaData,String,Float,Integer,create_engine
      engine = create_engine('sqlite:///college.db',echo = True)
meta = MetaData()

Comment: just for the future: if you have to post some code, you should edit your question, and not post in the comments. Moreover you should add some more precise tag to your question, in this case sql_alchemy (notice that when we asked 'what framework are you using' the correct answer were 'SQL Alchemy'!)

Answer (score 0):

Your select could be

```
s = select([Players.c.name, Players.c.number]).where(Players.c.number < 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time on my answer

Comment: luca.vercelli   when I try your code : s = select([Players.c.name, Players.c.number]).where(Players.c.number < 10)           it  run to error:                 OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: Players.number [SQL: 'SELECT "Players".name, "Players".number \nFROM "Players" \nWHERE "Players".number < ?'] [parameters: (10,)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: sory but I new with stackoverflow, I don't know how to put a code in my comment. Could you please take some look again?

Comment: The query seems correct to me. Does the table exist?

Comment: I don't know how to make a table from my code. I try to use sqlite studio but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: try https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#define-and-create-tables